# Accord shakes at 60-65 MPH

Tags: honda, accord, shaking

My 97 Accord 2.2 sedan shakes at 60-65 MPH. Just replaced wheel bearings, tie rod ends, upper control arms, front rotors, front brake pads, new tires w/balance and 4-wheel alignment but still shakes at 60-65 MPH. Axles are 3 years old, no grease on tires, no movement in joints. I feel a slight vibration in steering wheel very slight, feel a slight vibration in the driver seat. The car feels over all shaking at 60-65 mph mostly when accelerating. Anybody got any ideas? I'm out. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Two Ideas.
1.) Bent wheel(s). The tires may be new, but a bent wheel will still cause a vibration. Person balancing tires may have missed this. 
2.) Bad motor mount(s). The vibration is just especially noticeable at 60-65 MPH. The engine is literally twisting in its old, dry rotted, rubber mounts just enough at 60-65 to cause a very small portion of the engine OR trans axle to contact a portion of the chassis. Thus you feel the vibration in the drivers seat and steering wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Re-checking the balancing would be a cheap starting point, along with a close inspection of the wheels, as UAART1 pointed out. If you can locate the corner where the vibration comes from, exchange the wheels/tires positions around and see if the vibration source changes or follows a specific wheel.

After that, shaking under acceleration could be a CV joint.